# ERROR: UNION types integer and character varying cannot be matched [SQL State=42804]

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-view

I am doing union of two views but getting above error. Please help me to resolve this issue.
some values are hardcoded there and need to extract the same in final view.
I am using below query in redshift-

query:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS jgbl.vw_jgvcc_crm_case_activity CASCADE;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW jgbl.vw_jgvcc_crm_case_activity
AS
SELECT case_number as "CASE Number",
       parent_case_number as "Parent Case Number",
       date_opened as "Date Opened",
       number_of_questions as "Number of Questions",
       case_record_type as "CASE Record Type",
       NULL as "Sub Type",
       category as "Category",
       NULL as "Sub Category",
       country as Country,
       customer_type as "Customer Type",
       primary_account_subtype as "Primary Account Subtype",
       source as Source,
       call_center_location as "Call Center Location",
       region as Region,
       customer_region as "Customer Region",
       NULL as "AE",
       NULL as "PQC",
       'ASPAC' as datasource
FROM JG_ASPAC.vw_jgvcc_aspac_crm_activity

UNION ALL
       
SELECT case_num as "CASE Number",
       NULL as "Parent Case Number",
       open_dt as "Date Opened",
       cast(num_of_ques as integer) as "Number of Questions",
       rec_type_nm as "CASE Record Type",
       rec_sub_type as "Sub Type",
       cat_desc as "Category",
       sctgy_desc as "Sub Category",
       custm_latam_ctry_nm as Country,
       acct_type as "Customer Type",
       NULL as "Primary Account Subtype",
       src_in as Source,
       case when alph_fl='Y' then 'Alphanumeric' else 'LATAM Center' end as "Call Center Location",
       'LATAM' as Region,
       NULL as "Customer Region",  
       Case when rec_type_nm='AE/PQC' and rec_sub_type in ('ADVERSE EVENT','AE + PQC') then 'Y' else 'N' End as "AE",
       Case when rec_type_nm='AE/PQC' and rec_sub_type in ('AE + PQC', 'PRODUCT QUALITY COMPLAINT')  then 'Y' else 'N' End as "PQC",
       'LATAM' as datasource
FROM JG_LTM.vw_jgvcc_latam_crm_activity as v2
--LEFT JOIN jgbl.dim_iso_reg_cntry as t1 on t1.region = v2.ctry_iso2_cd 
with no schema binding;
```

error:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select * from jgbl.vw_jgvcc_crm_case_activity limit 10

### ERROR: Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 1, Type: Integer
Detail:

error:  Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 1, Type: Integer
code:      1207
context:   1.0
query:     87576
location:  :0
process:   query1_562_87576 [pid=0]
----------------------------------------------- [SQL State=XX000]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 4.81s

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? The first part of the union has one column defined as an integer but the corresponding column in the second part is a `varchar`. Either cast the integer to `varchar` or the `varchar` to `integer`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used cast function also.